# How to know if General Path is a Straight line or a curve?

Tags: java, awt

Is there a direct way to know if general path is a straight line?
and the width of the general path?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: i have a Java GeneralPath . i want to know if it is a straight line.And if it something like Line2D i want to know it's width

Answer (score 1):

assumming all points on the path are given in some `(x,y)` notation, you could say that a straight line is a group of points all "heading in the same direction", meaning that for every 2 consecutive points i and j, the ratio `(Xj-Xi)/(Yj-Yi)` (which is the slope) is the same, or close enough (be wary of rounding errors with floating numbers)